# Procedure or function has too many arguments specified

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, listview, stored-procedures

I am trying to get the value of the CategoryID so that I can insert that value into the database when an admin wants to update product features. The stored procedure that was written is for a ListView, so I was hoping I could put something hidden in there to get the ID. When I put the Hidden Field on the page and tried to get the ID, I got the error I mentioned in the title.

```
 <ul id="categories">
        <asp:ListView ID="lvAncestorCategories" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsCategoryAncestors">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <li><%# Eval("CategoryName") %></li>
            <li>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="CategoryID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CategoryID") %>' />
            </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemSeparatorTemplate> > </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </ul>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsCategoryAncestors" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProductsConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProductsConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="getCategoryAncestorsByProductID" 
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ProductID" QueryStringField="id" 
            Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="CategoryID" QueryStringField="id" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I did not write the stored procedure so I have no idea what it is doing, I got an error saying that my listview didn't have a value for @CategoryID so I added it to the stored procedure in the SELECT statement. Not knowing how the stored procedure works, I got the "too many arguments" error.

```
Dim featureSql As String = "INSERT INTO Marketing(ProductID, 
MarketingTypeID, MarketingTitle, MarketingData) 
VALUES ( @ProductID, 3, 'Feature', @MarketingData);
UPDATE Product SET ModifyDate = getdate(), 
ModifyUser = @ModifyUser 
WHERE ProductID = @ProductID; 
INSERT INTO Feature (FeatureTitle, CategoryID) 
VALUES (@FeatureTitle, @CategoryID)"

            Using cn As New SqlConnection
            (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
            ("LocalSqlServer").ConnectionString)

                Using cmd As New SqlCommand(featureSql, cn)

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FeatureTitle", txtFeature.Text))
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@CategoryID", CategoryID.Value))
                End Using
            End Using
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsCategoryAncestors" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProductsConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProductsConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="getCategoryAncestorsByProductID" 
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ProductID" QueryStringField="id" 
            Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="CategoryID" QueryStringField="id" Type="Int32"  />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Stored Procedure:

```
USE [Products]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[getCategoryAncestorsByProductID]    
Script Date: 11/11/2011 13:28:29 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getCategoryAncestorsByProductID]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@ProductID int
AS
BEGIN
-- This stored procedure gets all the lineage of a particular category

-- Create a temp table to hold the lineage in order
CREATE TABLE #FamilyTree (
    OrderNumber int,
    CategoryID int,
    CategoryName nvarchar(max)
)

DECLARE @CategoryID nvarchar(max)
SET @CategoryID = 
   (SELECT CategoryID 
    FROM CategoryLink 
    WHERE ProductID = @ProductID)

DECLARE @CategoryName nvarchar(max)
SELECT @CategoryName = CategoryName FROM Category WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID

-- Insert child category into table first giving it an OrderNumber of 1 
    -- the higher the number, the higher in the tree
INSERT INTO #FamilyTree VALUES (1,@CategoryID,@CategoryName)

-- Use this for the OrderNumber. Increment by 1 for each level.
DECLARE @OrderNumber int
SET     @OrderNumber = 2

-- Use this to hold the new CategoryID to add to the familytree table
DECLARE @AncestorID INT

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Category 
           WHERE CategoryID = 
          (SELECT ParentID FROM Category 
           WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID)) > 0
BEGIN

    SELECT @AncestorID = CategoryID, @CategoryName = CategoryName 
            FROM Category WHERE CategoryID = 
            (SELECT ParentID FROM Category 
            WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID)

    INSERT INTO #FamilyTree VALUES (@OrderNumber,@AncestorID,@CategoryName)
    SET @OrderNumber = @OrderNumber + 1
    SET @CategoryID = @AncestorID --Moves to the next CategoryID to see if it
                                            has any parents

END

--Returns Categories in order from Parents to Children
SELECT CategoryName FROM #FamilyTree ORDER BY OrderNumber DESC

DROP TABLE #FamilyTree

END
```

This is what I want to work:

```
Dim featureSql As String = "INSERT INTO Marketing
                            (ProductID, MarketingTypeID, MarketingTitle, MarketingData) 
                            VALUES ( @ProductID, 3, 'Feature', @MarketingData);
                            UPDATE Product 
                            SET ModifyDate = getdate(), ModifyUser = @ModifyUser 
                            WHERE ProductID = @ProductID; 
                            INSERT INTO Feature (FeatureTitle, CategoryID) 
                            VALUES (@FeatureTitle, @CategoryID)"
            Using cn As New SqlConnection
            (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
            ("LocalSqlServer").ConnectionString)

                Using cmd As New SqlCommand(featureSql, cn)

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FeatureTitle", txtFeature.Text))
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@CategoryID", CategoryID.Value))
                End Using
            End Using
```

Comment: Can you include a copy of the stored procedure?

Comment: I labeled the stored procedure so it's easier to find. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, don't know how I missed that, but we need to see the declaration and the parameters it accepts. i.e. create procedure getCategoryAncestorsByProductID(@id int) AS

Comment: Oops, sorry. Looks like I didn't select all of the text when I went to copy it. Is that what you were asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the CategoryID parameter:

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="CategoryID" QueryStringField="id" Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>
```

One additional note: Your stored procedure only returns CategoryName, not CategoryID. You should be able to fix this by changing the following line in the stored proc:

```
SELECT CategoryName FROM #FamilyTree ORDER BY OrderNumber DESC
```

to

```
SELECT CategoryName, AncestorID As CategoryID FROM #FamilyTree ORDER BY OrderNumber DESC
```

Comment: Well there are no errors on the page anymore so that rocks! Thanks!